# Newly Created Project but Toast Not Showing

Tags: java, android, toast

Why is my code not showing Toast? This is a new project with just a TextView and a Button to start. The emulator doesn't show Toast, what have I done wrong?

A little backstory. I am studying Java for 3 days now. Toast is showing yesterday until earlier today, but when I followed another tutorial in Youtube, I noticed that my Toast isn't showing anymore. Toast is showing on our other older projects though, not just on my newly created Projects and I wonder why.

Note that txtHello is changing it's text upon clicking the button.

```
package com.jbdelgado.test2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnGetCityID = findViewById(R.id.btnGetCityID);
        TextView txtHello = findViewById(R.id.txtHello);

        btnGetCityID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtHello.setText("Welcome!");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your textview text is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `View.OnClickListener` type does not work as a `Context`.